# How to change the minimum Severity level of Application Insights from the Azure Portal?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

In my ASP.NET Core application, I have configured the `ILoggerFactory` instance to output logs in Application Insights:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // By default, set the minimum severity level to Information.      
        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Later, `someClass` is being injected the `ILoggerFactory` instance and it is logging a Debug message:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     private ILogger _logger;

     public SomeClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     {
          _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(SomeClass));
     }

     public void Do()
     {
          _logger.LogDebug($"Some debug message");
     }
}
```

Application Insights is configured separately from the ASP.NET Core app, not as an extension.

Since I have configured Application Insights to only log message with a severity higher than or equal to Informational message, I do not see the Debug traces.

**Question**

Is there a way to change the minimum logging level from the Azure Portal for troubleshooting purposes without having to recompile the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible since you have defined in your code: `loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information);`

You could post the idea in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights).

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your appsettings.json - specifically add an ApplicationInsights section and adjust log level.

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

If your app did not have application insights, but installed application insights extension from Web Apps, then this should work.

Since you are already referring and setting log level in code, I am not 100% sure if this will work or not :(

Comment: works perfectly for the extension too. Thanks for the answer!!! exactly what I was looking for. I had the opposite problem where my minimum logging in the code was `trace`, but I wanted to hide some levels (like trace and debug).